# IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'java.lang.VirtualMachineError' does not implement interface 'java.lang.CharSequence'

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java

I am having weird problems with my code and I cannot explain anything that's happening. It's crashing on Marshmallow but not on Nougat which makes this more bizarre.

I can point to a line where the error occurs but the error itself is not clear. I am not sure what is crashing and how to prevent it. Here are the details:

The crash happens when I try to make a call to the server. To do this, I use `Retrofit` alongside `RxJava` and I do this in Kotlin. Here is my code:

```
fun login(username: String, password: String, callback: Login.OnLoginListener) {
    RestClient.getInstance().service
    .loginUser( //<- This line is crashing for no apparent reason
            Utils.RequestBodyParser.parseString(username),
            Utils.RequestBodyParser.parseString(password)
    )
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        { success ->
            (
            if (success.status)
                callback.onLoginSuccess()
            else
                callback.onLoginError()
            )
        },
        { error ->
            GenericErrorHandler.handleError(error, callback.retrieveContext())
        }
    )
}
```

Here is the logcat output:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'java.lang.VirtualMachineError' does not implement interface 'java.lang.CharSequence' in call to 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' (declaration of 'java.lang.Throwable' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
  at fi.hohtolabs.kuuratablet.network.WebController$Companion.login(WebController.kt:19)
  at fi.hohtolabs.kuuratablet.presenter.LoginPresenter.login(LoginPresenter.kt:31)
  at fi.hohtolabs.kuuratablet.dialog.LoginDialog.lambda$onResume$2$LoginDialog(LoginDialog.java:74)
  at fi.hohtolabs.kuuratablet.dialog.LoginDialog$$Lambda$2.onClick(Unknown Source)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Does anybody have any suggestions on what I should do? (I tried cleaning, rebuilding, restarting and invalidating caches, deleted the .gradle folder and all other stuff like that, nothing helps)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem had occurred only on Marshmellow devices and later was different one. Later i got the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and finally found out what the problem was.

The problem was that my libraries were over 64K methods and because `Instant Run` was on, there was no `multidex` error and whole application did not compile well.

Comment: Thank you, the cause of my problem was Instant Run (on)

Comment: i don't enable instant run, and i face the same error on android 6.0 only